# ASUS b550-f WIFi II : lspci shows mistaken wifi controler ! - Is this possible?

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, iwlwifi

I'm using Ubuntu Studio 22.04 with a 6.5.0-25-lowlatency Kernel on a asus rog strix b550-f gaming wifi II Motherboard. Wifi was working since installation right out of the box. But not stable.

Following the specs of my MB there has to be a intel@wifi AX2000 controller working in my system.

But this is the oput of  **lspci -k** says something different:

```
04:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7921K (RZ608) Wi-Fi 6E 80MHz
        Subsystem: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7921K (RZ608) Wi-Fi 6E 80MHz
        Kernel driver in use: mt7921e
```

After updating the pci device list the output remained the same.
I haven't found similar cases in the www.

How is that possible ? Any suggestions what to do ?

Comment: What specs? What I can find point to a [unspecified WiFi 6E controller](https://rog.asus.com/motherboards/rog-strix/rog-strix-b550-f-gaming-wifi-ii-model/). The Mediatek you show is a 802.11AX controller.